# Symfony2: form_widget call in twig throws exception "Catchable fatal error ... must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Form\FormView"

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

When I create a form inside my controller action like this:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('field_name')
    ->getForm();

return array(
    'form' => $form
);
```

... and I try to render this form in a twig template like this:

```
    <form action="{{ path('...') }}" method="post">
        {{ form_widget(form.field_name) }}
    </form>
```

... the `form_widget` invocation produces the following exception/error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer::searchAndRenderBlock() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Form\FormView, instance of Symfony\Component\Form\Form given, called in ...

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Your passing a Form when you should pass a View

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You have to pass an instance of `Symfony\Component\Form\FormView` instead of `Symfony\Component\Form\Form` to your view.

Fix this using ...

```
... ->getForm()->createView();
```

`FormBuilder::getForm` builds the **Form** object ... `Form::createView` then creates a **FormView** object.

Answer (score 2):

In Your Controller:

```
return array(
    'form' => $form->createView()
);
```

But if you want to send it to the view, it's a standard example:

```
return $this->render('@App/public/index.html.twig', array(
    'form'=>$form->createView()
));
```